# Declare and Put String array in HashMap in one step

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

I am trying to insert static data into a **HashMap** in Java like this:

```
HashMap<String,String[]> instruments = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
instruments.put("EURUSD", {"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"});
```

But the compiler doesn't like it.  The only way I found to insert that data into the HashMap is to declare the string array separately and then put it into the HashMap, like this

```
String[] instruDetails = {"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"};
instruments.put("EURUSD", instruDetails);
```

But it not very expressive, and hard to maintain

So my question is, is there a way to do the `put()` operation and string array declaration in one step/line?

Comment: Should be new String[]{ array elements}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do it:

```
instruments.put("EURUSD", new String[]{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"});
```

Comment: can you add to that array there?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English Just add a new string at the end. Maybe I don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 8):

To get it all in one sentence, use double-braces initialization: -

```
 HashMap<String,String[]> instruments = new HashMap<String, String[]>() {
     {
      put("EURUSD", new String[]{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"});
      put("EUR", new String[]{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"});
     }
 };
```

Comment: Otherwise known as an [_instance initializer block_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: It's also subclassing the `HashMap`.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Yup thats true.. But since OP wanted it in one step.. So I gave him..  :) :)

Comment: I think the actual question is why the `put` method call doesn't work. But still you introduced the OP with something new, I think. +1 :)

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks this is useful.  I have seen this construct with Listeners before but did not realise subclassing worked with HashMap too.  Will look to use this construct more often.

Answer (score 6):

I think you already got what works. But the reason that

```
instruments.put("EURUSD", {"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"});
```

doesn't work is because `{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"}`. `{}` is a syntactic sugar or short-cut in Java array for initialization. It comes with a constraint that it always has to go along with the array declaration statement, otherwise it's a syntax error.

Array declaration statement like

```
String[] array = {"1", "2"};
```

That way Java knows that the array that it needs to create for you is actually of `String` type elements.

If you break the above statement as follows

```
String[] array;
array = {"1", "2"};
```

It doesn't compile.

And with the `new String[]{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"}`, the compiler knows that it has to instantiate a new array which element type is `String` (`new String[]`) and initialize the newly instantiated array with values you provided (`{"4001","EURUSD","10000","0.00001","0.1","USD"}`).

Comment: but how to add to that array once you put it there?

Comment: You can get the array with the hash map. But you can't add to the if thats what you mean.

Comment: i did the thing that amit on the bottom recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095076/hashmapstring-arraylist-appending-arraylist-with-new-values-based-on-the-key) do you think that's a good solution? do you know how to print something like that by any chance?